# Dealing with unknown rude passenger

Tags: politeness, offensive-language

If in a train or bus some unknown elderly but rude passenger particularly a man, an old man, sitting on a seat which was already reserved by me, how to ask him to get up from there(the seat),
Is "**Get off my/the seat**" is a correct  expression when *I don't want to be polite to the old man*

Comment: “Get out of my seat!” would be more idiomatic.

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to be rude?

Comment: If you have to ask how to be rude, then you shouldn't try to be rude.  It is something that you can't fake and can't learn from a book or a website.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  But I'd say that I'm not trying to learn how to be rude but if someone unknown taking advantage of his old age, even after asking him politely he's not listening and is not following rules of reservation ((seat reservation is very important for a girl while travelling alone a long journey) ) then I don't think I should be politely ask him anymore... so I just wanted to know that, is "get off my seat" grammatical correct or not.. and I guess I should use 'out' instead of 'off'.

Answer (score 2):

Please note these usages:

**get off a train, boat, plane, bicycle, motorcycle, bus**: means of transportation or a surface.

- Hey, Johnny, get off that roof right now!

**get out of an x**: **when one is inside something**: Get out of a car, get out of a house.

- Hey, Johnny, get out of here! [leave this place: idiomatic]

For seats, we say **get out of my seat** as we considering a person to be sitting **in a seat**.

You would simply say: This is my reserved seat. Get out of it.

Whether old or young, not saying "please" can be seen a slightly curt or abrupt.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question:

- Get (the hell) out of my seat.
- This is my seat! Go take another one!
- Hey, you took my seat! Scat!

Anyway, you had better not be rude to elderly people!